# Extract specific line from text script

Tags: batch-file, set, extract

I am trying to get a script working to extract a specific line out of multiple text files at once. I have the script that will extract the line out of the text but I cannot get it to do this to multiple files.

What I have is an inventory file for each computer at my facility. I'm trying to extract like 16 which has the user's name so each file will have a different value on line 16 but it's always line 16.

Example file I'm trying to extract from:

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<center>
<table border=1>
<tr>
    <th>Full Name</th>
    <th>UserID</th>
    <th>IP Address</th>
    <th>Make</th>
    <th>Model</th>
    <th>Serial Number</th>
    <th>Default Printer</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>John Doe</td>
<td>USERNAME</td>
<td> 1. 1. 1.1
</td>
<td>Hewlett-Packard
</td>
<td>HP Compaq 8000 Elite SFF PC
</td>
<td>SERIALNUMBERX
</td>
<td>Microsoft XPS Document Writer
</td>
</tr>
</table></font>
<br />
Inventory taken on 2015/11/24 at 07:43:14. </center>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I'm wanting the script to extract the information to a text file so I can put it into a spreadsheet basically.

Here's my script so far. (The toop part I believe is the issue - the `FOR` command specifically) Sorry for my scripting ignorance. Trying to learn as I go.

```
@echo off &setlocal
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set filename=\\computername\c$\users\username\desktop\pcs.txt
for /F "tokens=*" %%a in ('type %filename%') do (
set file=%%a.html
)
set /a from=16
set /a till=16

for /f %%i in ('type "%file"^|find /v /c ""') do if %till% gtr %%i set /a till=%%i
set /a skip=from-1

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
<"!file!" (
for /l %%i in (1 1 %skip%) do set /p "="
for /l %%i in (%from% 1 %till%) do (
set "ln="
set /p "ln="
echo(!ln! >> c:\users\username\desktop\extracted.txt
 )
)
endlocal
pause
```

My pcs.txt file is setup like this:

```
pc1
pc2
pc3
```

Comment: You have to tell us by what criterium the line to extract is identified! Then you need describe what you expect your script to do and what it actually does! Just pasting some code is not enough if you expect good answers!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using psexec to run the file on each computer instead.

```
@echo off &setlocal
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "file=\\server\public\is\kixtartlogs\%computername%.html"
set /a from=16
set /a till=16

for /f %%i in ('type "%file%"^|find /v /c ""') do if %till% gtr %%i set /a till=%%i
set /a skip=from-1

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
<"!file!" (
for /l %%i in (1 1 %skip%) do set /p "="
for /l %%i in (%from% 1 %till%) do (
set "ln="
set /p "ln="
echo(%computername% !ln! >> \\computername\c$\users\username\desktop\extracted.txt
)
)
endlocal
```

PSEXEC command: 
`psexec @\\server\c$\pcs.txt -u domain\username -p password cmd /c \\server\c$\extract.bat`

Answer (score 0):

Always line 16?

```
@echo off
setlocal 
set count=0
for %%a in (*.txt) do call :getname %%a
set name
goto :eof

:getname
set /a count+=1
for /f "tokens=2 delims=<>" %%i in ('more +15 %1') do (set "name%count%=%%i" & goto :eof)
```

Comment: Is this supposed to go in with the script I already have? Yes it's always line 16.